# Validate parameters and string format

Tags: c#, string, format, string-formatting

I need to verify if a string format has correct number and position of parameters.
In my system advanced users (administrators) can configure a option with string format and select the params in combobox, one specific combobox to position in format. 
To save I need verify if this configuration is correct.

This is to generate a unique code to a record, this code is specific for each client.

In my screen I have a text box to the format, that can contain up to 6 items (or less), for each item i have one combobox.
The comboboxes contains a type of the value (ex. sequence, year, number, nothing (in case it's not required, etc).
I need verify if the format is correctly (ex. {0}-{1} is correct and {0}-{1}.{3} is wrong) and respective comboboxes are selected (ex. {0}-{1} require select a type in combobox 0 and 1)

--update--

I have resolved this question verifing the number of parameters in the string format is match with the number of values selecteds and the order of the values selecteds (ex. if the user keep any value empty and selected the next I have assumed this is incorrect) and I try generate a string with the format and values informed

Comment: Well, you can extract all `{xx}` patterns from your string and then check is something selected or not according to the `xx` value. It's hard to suggest more without seeing your code and clear undersnanding what's going on at your side.

Comment: Why is {0}-{1}.{3} incorrect? Perhaps he wants to ommit the 3rd parameter value?

Comment: In this case he can select the 4th parameters as 3rd. Using format {0}-{1}.{2} and selecting the parameter on the respective combobox. My idea is simplify for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a string to a particular pattern you should look into **Regular Expressions**.

It looks however, like there is more to it than simply pattern messaging - like maybe the user should be able to specify the desired pattern at run time? The question is a little unclear to be honest so I don't understand your full requirement.

Comment: If you don't understand OP's full requirement (frankly, I don't fully understand it) - then it's better to ask for clarification in comments. Right now you "answer" in fact doesn't answers OP's question at all and much more looks like a comment than answer.

Comment: Well if he's just looking for match with a static question, the first line answers his question perfectly. Given the OP is a little unclear, that may be all he/she needs.